# How can I move view's content up when iAd banner appears? (programatically in Swift)

Tags: swift, view, segue, iad, banner

I am adding an iAdBanner to a view controller programatically but have run into this problem: [text (label in scroll view) covers the ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daYdz.png)

I want the content of the view controller to shift up as to not cover the add, and I want to move the banner so it is on top of the scroll view as it is currently behind and can not be tapped.

I am trying to do this programatically as I have tried already in interface builder and keep running into problems such as displaying two ads after segueing out etc.

Any help would be appreciated

Here is my code so far:

```
var bannerView: ADBannerView!
    bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width / 2, y: view.bounds.size.height - bannerView.frame.size.height / 2)
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just from top of my head, but assuming you have `var scrollView`, you should be able to adjust it's frame(size of frame in which content appears) like this:

```
scrollView.frame.height = view.frame.height - bannerView.frame.size.height
```

Comment: Couldn't get your code specifically to work but it led me in the right direction and I've now done it by changing the contentInset of the scrollView

Comment: @ChrisWright you should post your solution as an answer for future readers.